# Is there a way to tell if a GUID column contains sequential or traditional / random GUID's?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, entity-framework

Have a table that is populated by Entity Framework 3.1.1 code.  The table contains a clustered index / primary key on ID which is defined as of type GUID with no default value.  Is there a way in SQL to look at the row data and tell if the GUID values are a traditional random GUID vs a sequential GUID?

Comment: Probably not easily because that would be dependent on the specific algorithm that was used to generate the `GUID`. What is the end problem you're trying to solve by figuring that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is to ORDER BY the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and if they are sequential you'll see a pattern.  EG

```
866381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
876381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
886381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
896381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8A6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8B6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8C6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8D6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8E6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
8F6381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
906381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
916381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
926381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
936381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
946381AE-0976-EB11-A396-5C80B6738BD2
```

But if the table doesn't have a DEFAULT of NEWSEQUENTIALID it's unlikely that they are sequential.